# What/such +a/an + noun

Tags: phrase-usage, exclamatives

Can we use "What/such +a/an + noun" without an adjective between "a/an" and "noun"? Because I've heard the sentence "What a beauty you are."

For example:

> What a dress
>   What a hamburger
>   Such a pair of shoes
>   Such a girl you are

And what if the noun was a plural noun or an uncountable noun? Can we still use this structure?

For example:

> What beauties (you are)
>   Such men
>   Such furniture

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does this sentence "What a fool I was to do it!" mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/212863/what-does-this-sentence-what-a-fool-i-was-to-do-it-mean) Also [Exclamation with “What or How”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/231025/) and [What's the difference between the exclamations “what” and “how”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/133145/)

Comment: Not really. But thank you so much for you helps

Comment: Then I'm not clear what you *are* asking about. Is it just a question of whether including an ***adjective*** makes any special difference? So for example, *I met John last night. What an evening we had!* is fine, but it could just as well have been *What an **enjoyable** evening* (or indeed, *What a **boring** evening*).